# Как поменять точку маршрута без его полной перестройки?

Tags: yandex-maps-jsapi

есть маршрут, как при изменении одного из адресов перестроить только одну из точек маршрута, а не полностью весь маршрут?

```
Пример https://jsfiddle.net/hmfeay5o/4/
```

Comment: Удалить старый маршрут и построить новый с учетом новых данных

Comment: Такой метод я знаю, поэтому спрашиваю можно ли так, как в вопросе =)

Comment: Почему вы хотите перестроить только одну из точек маршрута, а не весь маршрут?

Answer (score 1):

Можно поменять адрес и координаты точки маршрута, но это всё-равно приведёт к новому запросу и перестроению.

```
multiRoute.getWayPoints().get(0).model.setReferencePoint('Льва Толстого 16, Москва')
```

Пример: https://jsfiddle.net/7ntkxhcL/
Документация: https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/doc/jsapi/2.1-dev/ref/reference/multiRouter.WayPointModel-docpage/#method_detail__setReferencePoint